# InputDataStream.available() is always 0 Java Socket Client

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Why does this part of my client code is always zero ?

```
InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
int readCount = inputStream.available();  // >> IS ALWAYS ZERO
byte[] recvBytes = new byte[readCount];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int n = inputStream.read(recvBytes);
```

...

Comment: Is your socket connected?

Comment: @Nick If it wasn't connected, `getInputStream()` would have thrown an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably it's because no data has been received *yet*. `available()` tries to return the amount of data available *right now* without blocking, so if you call `available()` straight after making the connection, I'd expect to receive 0 most of the time. If you wait a while, you may well find `available()` returns a different value.

However, personally I don't typically use `available()` anyway. I create a buffer of some appropriate size for the situation, and just read into that:

```
byte[] data = new byte[16 * 1024];
int bytesRead = stream.read(data);
```

That will block until *some* data is available, but it may well return read than 16K of data. If you want to keep reading until you reach the end of the stream, you need to loop round.

Basically it depends on what you're trying to do, but `available()` is rarely useful in my experience.

Comment: Huh .. Perfect, I can change my logic to pass info about length of the stream prior and read it from there.. or I wait and use available() which i dont think wil be helpful in mycase.. but I opt for 1st option :) Thank u Jon :)

Comment: 'wait and use available' is completely pointless. Just block. That will block for the correct amount of time. Waiting won't and can't, because you don't know how long to wait for, so you will guess, and guess wrong, so you will oversleep: and then, calling available() to tell you how much to read doesn't do anything that just calling read() wouldn't already do.

Answer (score 1):

From the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29)

Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.
Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

A subclass' implementation of this method may choose to throw an IOException if this input stream has been closed by invoking the close() method.

The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

This method should be overridden by subclasses.

Here is a note to understand why it returns 0

In InputStreams, read() calls are said to be "blocking" method calls. That means that if no data is available at the time of the method call, the method will wait for data to be made available.

The available() method tells you how many bytes can be read until the read() call will block the execution flow of your program. On most of the input streams, all call to read() are blocking, that's why available returns 0 by default.

However, on some streams (such as BufferedInputStream, that have an internal buffer), some bytes are read and kept in memory, so you can read them without blocking the program flow. In this case, the available() method tells you how many bytes are kept in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) only returns the number of bytes that can be read from the stream **without blocking**. It doesn't mean that a read operation won't return anything.

You should check this value after a delay, to see it increasing.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few correct uses of available(), and this isn't one of them. In this case no data had arrived so it returned zero, which is what it's supposed to do.

Just read until you have what you need. It will block until data is available.